# Django prevent file duplicates in view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I need to prevent duplicate file saving.

Doing this in model:

```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      f = self.file
      digest = Document.gen_digest(f)
      qs = Document.objects.filter(hash=digest).first()
      if qs is not None:
          self.file = qs.file
      super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can reach a solution. But I need to send `messages` when duplicates have place. `messages` requires `request` - so I need to do this in a `view`.

But calling this sample in view, creates file with different name, which is default behaviour.

How to prevent saving duplicates and still forge `messages` if either, without overriding `FileStorage`?

Or any other advice would be just great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have working save method which satisfies you, I suggest to raise exception in it and then handle it in your view:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    f = self.file
    digest = Document.gen_digest(f)
    qs = Document.objects.filter(hash=digest)
    if not qs.exists():
        self.file = qs.file
    else:
        # May be some custom DuplicateFileError
        raise FileExistsError('Duplicate!!!')
    super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then in your view flash message in except block.